# Holomorphic Parameterintegral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have the following question in my complex analysis class:

Let $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a path and $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ a domain. Furthermore let $f: \operatorname{tr}(\gamma) \cdot G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous, so that the partial function $z\mapsto f(w,z)\quad \forall w \in \operatorname{tr}(\gamma)$ is holomorphic.
Consider $F: G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \quad F(z) = \int_\gamma f(w,z) \, dw.$

Show that:

1.) $F$ holomorphic on $G$ by using Morera's and Fubini's Theorem.

2.) $\displaystyle F^{(k)}(z)=\int_\gamma \frac{{\partial}^k f}{\partial z^k}(w,z) \, dw$ for  all $z \in G$ and $k \in  \mathbb{N}.$

My problem is that we never really used the theorems above, but I have the feeling that it will just calculating using the theorems. Furthermore, for the second question help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where you wrote $\operatorname{tr}(\gamma)\cdot G,$ might you have meant $\operatorname{tr}(\gamma)\times G,$ i.e. a Cartesian product?

Comment: If it's "just calculating using the theorems", does that mean you're difficulty is that you don't know how to use those theorems?

Comment: You wrote "we never really used the theorems above". Does that mean you saw them stated but you never saw how to use them? This seems not completely clear.

Comment: If you look at what Morera's theorem says, notice that its conclusion is that the function involved is holomorphic. So that's what you want to apply to $F.$ Thus, think about the integral of $F$ along certain kinds of closed curves. Then since $F$ is defined by an integral, you have an iterated integral, and it is to that that Fubini's theorem is to be applied.

Comment: Yes I meant the Cartesian product. My Problem is that we jusqt got the theroems stated in our lecture and I haven't seen it applied. But I try your hint. Thank you.